# "continuous" output with octal dump

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dump, octal

Using od in this way in the file test5MB:

```
od -a -An -v test5MB | head -110 | tr 'spnull' ' '
```

I got:

> P   !           *   *   *       P    R   O   G   R   A   M       D   E   M   U   X   V   A   X        R   U   N
>   N   I   N   G               1   3   :   3   2   :    3   1           1
>   9   -   A   P   R   -   8   5           P    H   O   E   N   I   X
>   F   A   M   I   L   Y           *    *   *
>   P               R    E   L   E   A   S   E       7   .   2       -
>   L   I   N    K       D   A   T   E       1   8   -   A   P   R   -   1
>   9    8   5       0   9   :   0   7   :   0   1   .   2   7
>
> ```
>                                                            P    !       *   *   *       @   L   1   3   .   D   M   X       *    *   *                                                        
>
>
>
>            P   L   I   N   E           8   0   0   0       8    0   0   0                   1               2   4                2   4    
>
>
>
>                            P   T   A   P   E           8   0    0   0                   1   M   P   L   X       F   3   2   I
>    1   6   0   0       I   N   1                            
>
>
>                                            P   R   E   E   L
>    4   0   4                               4   0   5        
>                    4   0   6                               4    0   7                               4   0   8                
>            4   0   9                                        
>                                                            P    R   E   E   L       4   1   0                               4    1   1
> ```
>
> 4   1   2
>                  4   1   3                               4   1   4
>                                  4   1   5
>
> ```
>            P   R   E   E   L       4   1   6                
>            4   1   7                               4   1   8
>                            4   1   9                        
>    4   2   0                               4   2   1        
>
>                            P   R   E   E   L       4   2   2
>                            4   2   3                        
>    4   2   4                               4   2   5        
>                    4   2   6                               4    2   7                                                        
>                                            P   R   E   E   L
>    4   2   8                               4   2   9        
>                    4   3   0                               4    3   1                               4   3   2                
>            4   3   3                                        
>                                                            P    R   E   E   L       4   3   4                               4    3   5
> ```
>
> 4   3   6
>                  4   3   7                               4   3   8
>                                  4   3   9
>
> ```
>            P   R   E   E   L       4   4   0                
>
>
>
>
>                            P   T   A   P   E           8   0    0   0                   2   P   H   X   I                    
>                        O   T   1                            
>
>
>                                            P   T   E   N   D
>
>
>
>
>                                                            P    F   R   M   T       B   3                           2   4    
>                                2                            
>
>
>
>            P   E   D   T   B           1   6   3   5        
>                9   9   9   9                                
>    1                                                        
>
>
>                            P   S   E   Q           R   S   P    L       O   U   T   1       E   N   D   C
> ```

The problem is that I should get it in this format (the bold letters aren't needed):

> P!  *** PROGRAM DEMUXVAX RUNNING   13:32:31  19-APR-85  PHOENIX FAMILY**
>         P   RELEASE 7.2 - LINK DATE 18-APR-1985 09:07:01.27                              P!  **@L13.DMX ***
>   PLINE  8000 8000    1   24   24
>   PTAPE  8000    1MPLX F32I 1600 IN1
>   PREEL 404       405       406       407       408       409
>   PREEL 410       411       412       413       414       415
>   PREEL 416       417       418       419       420       421
>   PREEL 422       423       424       425       426       427
>   PREEL 428       429       430       431       432       433
>   PREEL 434       435       436       437       438       439
>   PREEL 440
>   PTAPE  8000    2PHXI           OT1
>   PTEND
>   PFRMT B3      24         2
>   PEDTB  1635      9999         1
>   PSEQ  RSPL OUT1 ENDC

Can this format be achieved directly from the output of od? the best is using od and some bash/shell tricks.

Thanks in advance for any hint on this,

Comment: What is `tr 'spnull' ' '` even supposed to be? I suspect that doesn't do what you think it does - it will replace any occurrences of 's', 'p', 'n', 'u' or 'l' with a space...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `xxd`, specifically with the `-p` option.

I can't say much more without an input file :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer dude, I can share the file but it's 5MB so not sure if it is possible to upload files that big here

Comment: You can grab 2kB from the start with `dd if=yourFile bs=2048 count=1 > start.bin`